# Importing images into visio using VBA

Tags: vba, image, excel, import, visio

I'm using VBA to import data from an Excel file into Visio, and I need to also include an image in the Visio file that isn't in my Excel file but is saved locally. I need to be able to manipulate the image similarly to a shape object (ie; set its width/height/position using VBA, like Shape.Cells ("width") = X etc.)

I've looked extensively online for a solution, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define page where you want insert picture. Read more about [Page.Import Method (Visio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/page-import-method-visio)

```
Set shp = ActivePage.Import("C:\Users\surrogate\Pictures\new.png")  
shp.Cells("PinX").Formula = "100 mm"  
shp.Cells("PinY").Formula = "150 mm"
```

Comment: Oh now I see. My Visio page was a separate Object called AppVisio created using my custom function, so I had to have: Dim shp As Object Set shp = AppVisio.ActivePage.Import("C:\Users\surrogate\Pictures\new.png")

Answer (score 1):

when you insert your images in visio, it became as shapes.

[VisShapeTypes Enumeration (Visio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/visshapetypes-enumeration-visio)

And you can set their width/height/pinx/piny like as for native MS Visio shapes

Comment: I figured that might be the case, thank you. How do I actually import the shape through VBA though? Trying Set image = Import(C:\ImagePath) or something similar doesn't work.